# PLSQL how to parse data between <#include "xxx" />

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, plsql

In DB I have data like:

```
"text moretext <#include "notification.bar.account.locked.body.ftl" /> sda text
moretext moretext <#include "notification.bar.account.unlocked.body.ftl" /> fsd text."
```

how to get back everything what is inside include block, so get back:

```
notification.bar.account.locked.body.ftl
   notification.bar.account.unlocked.body.ftl
```

and each in own row if possible

Comment: `regexp_substr(your_text, '<#include "(.*?)" />', 1, 1, '', 1)` [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9349/2)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It deserves an answer I think

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thank you. It works but I get just first one and not both. Can i get both, each in own row? Thx

Comment: @senzacionale - since you've been handed 90% of the solution I suggest that you take this as a challenge, read up a bit on regular expressions, and figure out how to do this on your own. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, `regexp_substr(your_text, '<#include "(.*?)" />', 1, n, '', 1)` [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ef5e/1)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff please write it as an answer that i can accept it. Here in comments I do not have this possibility. Thx

Comment: Sorry, I'm too lazy.  Maybe someone else would write complete answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions seem like the obvious answer to address this specific string. In this case I'd use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#SQLRF51691) to replace all parts of the string that are not what you want:

```
SQL> with the_data as (
  2  select '"text moretext <#include "notification.bar.account.locked.body.ftl" /> sda text
  3  moretext moretext <#include "notification.bar.account.unlocked.body.ftl" /> fsd text."' as str
  4    from dual
  5         )
  6  select regexp_replace(str, '(.*<#include\s")(.*)("\s/>.*)', '\2')
  7    from the_data;

REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'(.*<#INCLUDE\S")(.*)("/>.*)','\2')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
notification.bar.account.locked.body.ftl
notification.bar.account.unlocked.body.ftl
```

(Yes, that's a single column with a carriage return between 2 strings).

To break down the expression, it basically says

1. Match anything (`.*`)
2. Match the string `<#include` followed by a space (`\s`)
3. Match anything (`.*`)
4. Match a space (`\s`) followed by the string `/>`
5. Match anything (`.*`)

The parenthesis are groups; you only want the second group, which is what `\2` means in the third parameter of the function.

More generally, if you're passing HTML/XML or HTML like entities then using a proper HTML/XML parser would be the preferred choice.

---

For completeness, I've just seen [Egor Skriptunoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304821/plsql-how-to-parse-data-between-include-xxx/25308137#comment39443222_25304821) comment, which suggests a similar approach using [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303)

```
regexp_substr(your_text, '<#include "(.*?)" />', 1, n, '', 1)
```

The only real difference is that you'd have to run this twice in order to find both occurrences by replacing `n` with the occurrence of this pattern in the string. If you don't know the number of occurrences beforehand then this might cause some problems. If you do then it's slightly cleaner than using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: Result of your query [may contain](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33950) some unwanted trash

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select substr(text,instr(text,chr(34),1,1)+1, instr(text,chr(34),1,2) - instr(text,chr(34),1,1)-1  ) from temp
```

Edit:

If you need something more intelligent and are not aware about the position of include block in the text then we can first search for include block and pick the main stuff out of it.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SUBSTR(text,instr(text, '<#',1), instr(text, '>',1) ),instr(text,chr(34),1,1)+1, instr(text,chr(34),1,2) - instr(text,chr(34),1,1)-1 )
FROM temp;
```

Let me know if it is not what you were looking for.

Edit Again to return 2 different columns.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SUBSTR(text,instr(text, '<#',1,1), instr(text, '/>',1,1) ),instr(text,chr(34),1,1)+1, instr(text,chr(34),1,2) - instr(text,chr(34),1,1)-1 ),
, SUBSTR(SUBSTR(text,instr(text, '<#',1,2), instr(text, '/>',1,2) ),instr(SUBSTR(text,instr(text, '<#',1,2), instr(text, '/>',1,2) ),chr(34),1,1) + 1, instr(SUBSTR(text,instr(text, '<#',1,2), instr(text, '/>',1,2) ),chr(34),1,2) - instr(SUBSTR(text,instr(text, '<#',1,2), instr(text, '/>',1,2) ),chr(34),1,1)-1 )
FROM temp;
```

So now it will return two different columns
I know this has gotten a little complex but instead from , if you use union you will get these results in different rows, provided this text is in one columns.

Comment: Hello, first example is really good but also return back just notification.bar.account.locked.body.ftl and not also notification.bar.account.unlocked.body.ftl. Can you change it to return more then one result